# ASP.NET Import Namespace Error in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces, global-asax

```
<%@ Import Namespace="project.name.folder"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="project" %>`
```

In my Projectmap exists many Projectclasses. One is called project and another is called project.name.

If i compile the ASP.NET Program it says:

> the type or namespace name 'name' in namespace 'project' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The problem began since i changed the Programmplattform to x64. The compiler thinks that .folder is a folder from the other Project 'project' but its a folder from Project 'project.name'.

Tried Solutions:

- put project import over the other import
- clear Project and rebuild
- checked imported dlls

[image]

Comment: Could you put a screen of your project and classes?

Comment: The code above is modified and simplified to focus the problem. I cant do a Screen cause of code data privacy...

Comment: Which view engine are you using ? razor or aspx

Comment: i use aspx as engine

Comment: I don't get your question. From the first pharagraph, I understand that one of your project classes is called project.name, and that's not possible. Can't you put the namespace and class name of your problematic classes?

Comment: i added a screen from a example Project. As you can see there are 2 class libs and one is called project.name. The compiler thinks that project.name ==> .name is a folder from the other class lib project.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screen and your question:

1. Check that your website project references both project.name project and project project (damn, you could have used another name here :P)
2. Folder at the moment seems to be an empty folder, so you can't do this import: `<%@ Import Namespace="project.name.folder"%>` because that namespace does not exists.
3. In my image, this is working (in my case works because I've created an item "FolderClasscs" inside folder and its namespace is Project.Name.Folder)
4. I wouldn't suggest these names due to namespace conflicts

[image]

Comment: My Screen its just a fast simplified Project to show up my problem. Do you set the target plattform from the classes on x64? (right click on class lib, properties, build, x64. If i put my class on any cpu, global.asax find the import but not on x64..

Comment: Quite strange... The target platform should not impact on the using/import directives. I changed to x64 on my solution and it still builds fine.

Comment: Could it be that a .dll in my Projectclasses that only works on x86 create this error? In my main Project are over 20 Project classes which communicate under each other. I think no one can help me there without more Informations about this project. But thanks anyway Juan for trying to help me!

Comment: Yep, maybe it's hard without the project itselft. To give a clue, I think that the reason is not the one you're saying. I think that the target platform could give you issues in runtime, but if all of the projects you're importing compile correctly, then your import should work. Good luck!